# Oracle Integration Run Time Sharing Issue

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using Oracle Self hosted IR in my Dev data factory. Now I want to share this IR to another Data Factory  and I've followed the below instructions to create the linked IR.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime

But I'm receiving the below permission issue.

```
Failed to list the data factories. 
Detail:{
    "odata.error":{
        "code":"Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message":{
            "lang":"en",
            "value":"Guest users are not allowed to perform this action."
        },
        "requestId":"841a68c6-645d-43c0-bd6c-e592208880c1",
        "date":"2019-02-08T08:03:19"
    }
}
```

The logged in user into Azure Portal is having Guest but at the data factory (both) level he is the Owner for two Data Factories.

I'm searching the data factory by name and the ID for grating the permissions.

How can we identify the MSI of data factoy?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the MSI of data factory from the "Properties" of your data factory on the portal. Here is an example:
[image]